# How to select only edges that are fully contained in the selection rectangle (in the side view)?

Tags: selection-tools

If I choice the right side view, then when I use rectangular selection, I get the following result.

[image: Selection in the side view]

How to get the  only edges that are fully contained in the selection rectangle like I get in the perspective view.

[image: Selection in the perspective view]

Comment: you could first select in vertex mode, after selection is done, change to edge mode

Comment: In that particular case it's probably easiest to switch to vertex (1 on the keyboard) and x-ray mode (ALT-Z). Box select the vertices and then switch back to edge mode (2 on the keyboard. You'll then have the edge between the two selected vertices selected.

Comment: @Chris Great minds think alike! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason: but i am not sure whether OP is happy with it... ;)

Comment: @Chris True! Unfortunately you often have no way of knowing whether a quick comment has been of any use to the person asking the question.

Comment: Thank you, guys, but the approach of @Martynas Žiemys looks more native or something.

Comment: @JohnEason Actually, when you're in X-Ray or Wireframe mode, it is not necessary to switch to vertex mode. In these modes only fully contained edges will be selected. Something similar when you are on face select: in X-Ray or Wireframe mode only faces will be selected which center dot is in the selection.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Box selection works in a smart way - (1)if you drag over only parts of some edges, it selects the ones that you only "touch", but (2)if the selection includes full edges, it selects only the ones that are fully inside the rectangle. It seems to work the exact same way in perspective and in side views. The issue is that the edge that is not visible is behind the one that is and so the first scenario happens. If you enable x-ray mode(alt+z) then the hidden edge is "visible" to the selection and if it is the only one fully in the selection it will work the way you wish:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works!

Comment: Aaah! ....learn something every day.. :)